# Error while running React application using `npm run dev`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the error when I run `npm run dev` in the terminal: [Error while running React app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4Q75.png)

Please help me with this error.

This is how I build a normal React project.

1. `npm create vite@latest`
2. `npm install`
3. `npm run dev` This is when the error aquire.

Comment: https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/3612#issuecomment-1495469808

Comment: Thank you @Jayce444, the error is now fixed.